# Jquery with Sliing page and sliding images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i just finished the 5 Sliding page site, which each page i have image slider.

i am using Image slider within Page Slider. when i am trying to use the same image slider with different images for page slide 3, its not working. please help would be great Appreciate.

i am not good in Jquery, so i did lot of research and no luck...

---

```
                            <div id="address">
                            <img src="images/address.png" width="300" height="119" alt="address">
                            </div>

                            <div id="shop">
                            <img src="images/shop.jpg" width="300" height="225" alt="Shop">
                            </div>

                            <div class="photocradle" style="Position:absolute; top:58px; left:360px;width:690px;height:420px;float:right;text-align:right;"></div>

                             <div id="kitchen2">
                   <script type="text/javascript"> 
                  $(function(){
                var options = {
                firstImageIndex: 0,
                borderWeight: 0 },
                                                                            params = {
                            sources: [
                            {
                                    preview: 'images/previews/1.jpg',
                original: 'images/originals/1.jpg',}, 
                                    {
                                                                preview: 'images/previews/2.jpg',
                original: 'images/originals/2.jpg',}, 
                                    {
                                                                preview: 'images/previews/3.jpg',
                original: 'images/originals/3.jpg',}, 
                                    {
                                                                preview: 'images/previews/4.jpg',
                original: 'images/originals/4.jpg',}
                       ]
                };
                $( '.photocradle' ).photocradle( params, options );
                                 }); </script>
                            </div>
```

```
                            <div id="address">
                            <img src="images/address.png" width="300" height="119" alt="address">
                            </div>

                            <div id="shop">
                            <img src="images/shop.jpg" width="300" height="225" alt="Shop">
                            </div>

                            <div class="photocradle" style="Position:absolute; top:58px; left:360px;width:690px;height:420px;float:right;text-align:right;"></div>

                             <div id="kitchen3">
                   <script type="text/javascript"> 
                  $(function(){
                var options = {
                firstImageIndex: 0,
                borderWeight: 0 },
                                                                            params = {
                            sources: [
                            {
                                    preview: 'images/previews/5.jpg',
                original: 'images/originals/5.jpg',}, 
                                    {
                                                                preview: 'images/previews/6.jpg',
                original: 'images/originals/6.jpg',}, 
                                    {
                                                                preview: 'images/previews/7.jpg',
                original: 'images/originals/7.jpg',}, 
                                    {
                                                                preview: 'images/previews/8.jpg',
                original: 'images/originals/8.jpg',}
                       ]
                };
                $( '.photocradle' ).photocradle( params, options );
                                 }); </script>
                            </div>
```

i used the method below, and on first page slider, i am getting 2 image  overlap, i need 3 small images in 3 page slider with different size

Link is http://theshoaibahmed.com/jquery.photocradle-0.4.2.js

here is the link for what i am trying to achieve and not working

http://www.theshoaibahmed.com/roman/

if you noticed i used

photocradle.$area = $( '' )
    .appendTo( $( "#kitchen2") );

what option i can use so if i have to use 3 more image slider with different size, i would be able to use it.

Comment: i think u forgot to add reference of jquery and jquery.photocradle-0.4.0.js

Answer (score 0):

That is because you have 2 different divs with same name class on the same page, and photocradle is confused to which one should he append the code.

Do like this:

```
<div id="first" class="photocradle" style="Position:absolute; top:58px; left:360px;width:690px;height:420px;float:right;text-align:right;"></div>
```

-

```
$( '#first' ).photocradle( params, options );
```

-

```
<div id="second" class="photocradle" style="Position:absolute; top:58px; left:360px;width:690px;height:420px;float:right;text-align:right;"></div>
```

-

```
$( '#second' ).photocradle( params, options );
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link when i tried the technique above

http://www.theshoaibahmed.com/roman/